# Angular module ng-table is duplicating part of a path in URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm using angular module ng-table (http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-table) in my rails - angular app. The problem is, ng-table is duplicating part of a path in my URLs.

E.G.: The URL should be `http://host.com/hostings/1/email-accounts` but somewhere in the module it becomes `http://host.com/hostings/1/email-accounts#/email-accounts`.

My application works in following way:

1. User visits http://host.com/hostings/1/email-accounts
2. Rails renders a view with ng-controller directive and some basic layout(in this case, ng-controller="EmailAccountsCtrl")
3. Angular controller populates the view

Bottom line: I'm not using angular for routing.

This is my **angular config**:

```
admin = angular.module('admin', ['ngResource', 'hostingsModule', 'ui.bootstrap.modal', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);

admin.config(function($locationProvider, $httpProvider) {    
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'https://sadmin.igloonet.cz'
});
```

**EmailAccountsCtrl**:

```
hostingsModule.controller('EmailAccountsCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$filter', 'Hosting', 'EmailAccount', 'ngTableParams', function($scope, $q, $filter, Hosting, EmailAccount, ngTableParams) {
    var hostingId;

    $scope.emailAccounts = [];
    $scope.hosting = findHosting(hostingId);

    $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
        $liveFiltering: true,
        page: 1,
        total: 0,
        count: 10,
        sorting: {
            email: 'asc'
        }
    });

    $scope.$watch('tableParams', function(params) {
        if (angular.equals({},params.filter)) {
            $scope.tableParams.disabledButton = true;
        } else {
            $scope.tableParams.disabledButton = false;
        }

        $scope.loading = true;
        EmailAccount.all(hostingId, params.url()).success(function(data) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.emailAccounts = data.emailAccounts;
            $scope.tableParams.total = data.total;
        });
    });
}]);
```

And a part of a controller of **ng-table directive**:

```
controller: [
    "$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {          
      var updateParams;          
      $scope.params = $scope.params || {
        page: 1,
        count: 10
      };

      // When I log the url here, it's still correct

      $scope.$watch('params.filter', (function(value) {

        // When I log the url here, it has the part with #email-accounts already appended

        if ($scope.params.$liveFiltering) {
          console.log(updateParams());
          updateParams(value);
          return $scope.goToPage(1);
        }
      }), true);
      updateParams = function(newParams) {
        newParams = angular.extend($scope.params, newParams);
        $scope.paramsModel.assign($scope.$parent, new ngTableParams(newParams));
        return $scope.params = angular.copy(newParams);
      };
      $scope.goToPage = function(page) {
        if (page > 0 && $scope.params.page !== page && $scope.params.count * (page - 1) <= $scope.params.total) {
          return updateParams({
            page: page
          });
        }
      };
      $scope.changeCount = function(count) {
        return updateParams({
          page: 1,
          count: count
        });
      };
      $scope.doFilter = function() {
        return updateParams({
          page: 1
        });
      };
      return $scope.sortBy = function(column) {
        var sorting, sortingParams;
        if (!column.sortable) {
          return;
        }
        sorting = $scope.params.sorting && $scope.params.sorting[column.sortable] && ($scope.params.sorting[column.sortable] === "desc");
        sortingParams = {};
        sortingParams[column.sortable] = (sorting ? "asc" : "desc");
        return updateParams({
          sorting: sortingParams
        });
      };          
    }
  ],
```